# Scala swing all button same width

Tags: swing, scala, layout

I have a BoxPanel of buttons in my scala swing app that looks ugly to me because the buttons are all different sizes.  I had changed it to a GridPanel but then they filled the panel vertically aswell which I found uglier.  How can I have all buttons fill the width of the BoxPanel but stay their perferred height?

I tried a work around, shown below, where the panel sets all the contents to the max width but it had no effect.

```
val buttons = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
  contents += new Button("Normal Button")
  contents += new Button("small")
  contents += new Button("Significantly larger button than the rest")

  val maxWidth = contents map { 
    (button: Component) => button.preferredSize 
  } maxBy { _.width }

  contents foreach { 
    (button: Component) => button.preferredSize = maxWidth
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make the above workaround work or a way that isn't a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A s discussed in [*Box Layout Features*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#features), "if all the components have identical X alignment, then all components are made as wide as their container." Override the button's `getMaximumSize()` implementation as shown below to return an arbitrary width and the button's preferred hight. Change `setHorizontalAlignment()` and/or resize the frame to see the effect.

```
@Override
public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
    return new Dimension(
        Short.MAX_VALUE, getPreferredSize().height);
}
```

[image]

Code as shown:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34443937/230513 */
public class ButtonBoxTest {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new JPanel() { //arbitrary filler

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(320, 240);
            }
        });
        f.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(btnPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        btnPanel.add(createButton("Button 1"));
        btnPanel.add(createButton("Button 2"));
        btnPanel.add(createButton("Long Button 3"));
        btnPanel.add(createButton("Button 4"));
        btnPanel.add(createButton("Button 5"));
        return btnPanel;
    }

    private JButton createButton(String name) {
        final JButton b = new JButton(name) {

            @Override
            public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
                return new Dimension(
                    Short.MAX_VALUE, getPreferredSize().height);
            }
        };
        b.setAlignmentX(0.5f);
        b.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.RIGHT);
        return b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new ButtonBoxTest()::display);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TrashGod is right but I figured I would post an answer translated to Scala as his is in Java. I got my original workaround to work by replacing `preferredSize` with `maximumSize`, thanks to reading trashgod's answer.

```
val buttons = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
  contents += new Button("Normal Button")
  contents += new Button("small")
  contents += new Button("Significantly larger button than the rest")

  val maxWidth = contents map { 
    (button: Component) => button.maximumSize
  } maxBy { _.width }

  contents foreach { 
    (button: Component) => button.maximumSize = maxWidth
  }
}
```

I was also able to get a solution translated from trashgod's answer with just

```
private def equalButtons(name: String): Button = {
  new Button(name) {
    maximumSize = new Dimension(Short.MaxValue, maximumSize.height)
  }
}

val buttons = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
  contents += new equalButtons("Normal Button")
  contents += new equalButtons("small")
  contents += new equalButtons("Significantly larger button than the rest")
}
```